# c# LINQ : Get all int in Model

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to know how I can get all int value in a model LINQ.
Example : My Model

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int a{ get; set; }
        public int b{ get; set; }
        public int c{ get; set; }
    }
```

And I want to get only the int value to do for example a Sum with linq (a+b+c):

```
        var sumOfInt= Result.Where(t => t.GetType== int ).Sum()
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is `Result` a single instance of `MyClass` or a sequence of instances of `MyClass`? You'd need to use reflection to achieve that. But maybe if you add some context and explain what you are _actually_ trying to achieve, there maybe a better overall design.

Comment: Just to be sure. You want to get the sum of all int values of one instance ot the sum of all int values of many instances?

Comment: That's a strange request. Why don't you add a method to your class that generates that sum?  LINQ works with collections while you want to read arbitrary properties. That's a job for Reflection. The resulting code would be rather ugly and fragile. For example, if your class had an integer `Id` property it would also be included in the sum

Comment: From @VladimirArustamian: 
I'm pretty sure you don't need to solve that task. Find a better way to design your application. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve? Most likely there are other, better ways to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can to it like this:

```
MyClass cls = new MyClass();
cls.a = 10;
cls.b = 20;
cls.c = 30;
int sum = cls.GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(int))
    .Sum(x => (int)x.GetValue(cls));
```

Comment: `GetProperties()` returns an array, that's why `ToList()` is redundant

Answer (score 7):

First, let me say that this does not sound like a good idea. If you later add an `ID` property to your model, do you really want your code to automatically add its value to your sum?

That said, should you happen to have very good reasons for doing this, you can perform the following steps:

- [Use reflection to get all the properties of the class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/737151/87698),
- [filter to those with type `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3723934/87698),
- [extract the values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx) and sum them.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sum up `a`, `b`, `c` values from `MyClass` you can use *Reflection* and *Linq*:

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Reflection;
  ...   

  MyClass source = ...

  var sum = source
    .GetType()
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance |
                   BindingFlags.Public | 
                   BindingFlags.NonPublic) // you may want not to read non-public props
    .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.PropertyType == typeof(int))
    .Sum(p => (int) p.GetValue(source));
```

Comment: This would work as long as there aren't any ID properties. The OP should explain what the actual goal is

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: I agree "...get all int value.." sounds very suspecious (shall, say *private* properties be included into the sum, whay shall we sum up integer *Ids* if any are in the class..)

Answer (score 1):

`Result.SelectMany(r => new[] { r.a, r.b, r.c }).Sum()`

But it's unclear what exactly do you need? Do you need a code which can (through Reflection) get all `int` properties of `MyClass`? Or you just need to flatten all of them into single `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Whoever downvoted this should consider that this is the only *sensible* solution given the OP's question. Using reflection would result in ugly and slow code. The OP should rethink the design

Comment: Might as well be `Select(r => r.a + r.b + r.c).Sum()`.  No need to create a bunch of unneeded intermediate arrays.

Comment: @juharr even better, `Select(r=>r.Periphery()).Sum()` where `Periphery()=>a+b+c;`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Also a good approach, but I definitely agree that if you find that you want to use reflection then 9 times out of 10 you should probably rethink your design.

Comment: @juharr every answerer and commenter to this question agrees

Answer (score 0):

If you want do it with linq  you can use 
[Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710(v=vs.110).aspx) Another answers provide details and examples for this way. But If you want *dynamically* get all properties with in type -The simply way is [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Note that Reflection hits by performance and usually we should use this ways only if another approach is impossible. That is why i do not suggest use reflection. Instead of it i provide example with helper method inside your class

```
    class Model
    {

        private Dictionary<string, int> fieldsForSum = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        private int age;
        private int year;

        public int Age
        {
            get { return age; }
            set
            {
                bool isContain = fieldsForSum.ContainsKey(nameof(age));
                if (isContain)
                    fieldsForSum[nameof(age)] = value;
                else
                    fieldsForSum.Add(nameof(age), value);
                age = value;
            }
        }

        public int Year
        {
            get { return year; }
            set
            {

                bool isContain = fieldsForSum.ContainsKey(nameof(year));
                if (isContain)
                    fieldsForSum[nameof(year)] = value;
                else
                    fieldsForSum.Add(nameof(year), value);
                year = value;
            }
        }

        public int CalcIntFields()
        {
            return fieldsForSum.Values.Sum();
        }
    }
```

and example of usage

```
        var m = new Model
        {
            Age = 4,
            Year = 3
        };
        var sum = m.CalcIntFields();//7
        m.Year = 1;
        sum = m.CalcIntFields(); //5
```

Comment: Reflection *adds* a lot of overhead. Just check all answers that use expressions like `r => r.a + r.b + r.c` and those that use reflection.

Comment: you don't understand me. Of course reflection hits by preformance. It's clear for everyone.  I mean that **implementation** with  using reflection is more easy  that Expression way. and I updated post for clarify

Comment: That's what I meant also. `r => r.a + r.b + r.c` *is* an Expression. The question you linked to asks something *completely* different - how to generate queries dynamically. For which, you don't need an expression tree most of the time

Comment: In any case, this should be a comment, not an answer. You do mention reflection but don't provide more information or a solution, as the other questions here