# Get the types of members properties of a Class

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class with 3 properties:

```
  public class person
   {
     public int age   {get; set;}
     public string adress {get; set;}
     ...
   }
```

Is there a way using reflection to get the types of the attribues saying I wanna have int and string

I tried using

```
typeof(person).GetProperty("age")
```

but I did not succeeded to get int (ans string for the adress attribute)

Thank you in advance

Comment: These are not attributes, those are properties :) Also have you looked at [PropertyInfo.PropertyType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype?view=net-6.0)? Maybe something along the lines of `typeof(person).GetProperty("age")?.PropertyType.Name`?

Comment: @Trevor Thnks I did the modifications

typeof(person).GetProperty("age")?.PropertyType.Name returns Nullable1

Comment: you're welcome, glad to help.

Comment: Also this may help you as well [Using PropertyInfo to find out the property type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723934/using-propertyinfo-to-find-out-the-property-type)

Comment: @Trevor: Kind of but I found that I have to use 

'typeof(Person).GetProperty("age").PropertyType == typeof(Nullable<System.Int32>)

But It cant retreive that automatically

Comment: Depending on use case and or implementation of course, but it doesn't change how to get the property type. I assumed from your post you wanted the string representation of the types. If not you can drop the `.Name`.

Comment: @Trevor I had to use something like

Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(person).GetProperty("age").PropertyType).Name

Sorry I figured out that I missed the int? age from the declaration

Comment: It's ok, glad you've got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `Name` of the `PropertyType` property of the `PropertyInfo` object returned by `GetProperty()`:

```
var t = typeof(person).GetProperty("age");
Console.WriteLine(t.PropertyType.Name);
```

returns

> Int32

Live demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iZG5IG

Documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperty?view=net-6.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo?view=net-6.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype?view=net-6.0#system-reflection-propertyinfo-propertytype