# Getting the type of a class property c#

Tags: c#

I need to determine the property type of a class's properties at runtime so that I can perform data conversion before assignment. I've seen a bunch of answers on SO, such as:

[Using PropertyInfo to find out the property type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723934/using-propertyinfo-to-find-out-the-property-type)

But clearly I must be doing something wrong because the following test code always drops to the default case:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Seller { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PaymentDate { get; set; }
    public double? PaymentAmount { get; set; }
    public string PaymentMethod { get; set; }
}....
```

And the test code.

```
string s = "";
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties();
...
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
    {
        switch (propertyInfo.PropertyType)
        {
            case Type _ when propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string):
                    s = "It's a string!";
                break;
            case Type _ when propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(int):
                    s = "It's an int!";
                break;
            case Type _ when propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(double):
                    s = "It's a double!";
                break;
            case Type _ when propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime):
                s = "It's a datetime!";
                break;
            default:
                ...
                break;
        }
    }
...
```

There is a propertyInfo returned for Id, Seller ,etc..., but nothing matches in the switch. I simply need to identify the type of each property in the class.

I also tried using TypeCode, but also no luck as variable tc always has the value of object, not sure why:

```
Type pt = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
TypeCode tc = Type.GetTypeCode( pt );

switch (tc)
{
    case TypeCode.DateTime:
        s = "DateTime";
        break;
    case TypeCode.Int32:
        s = "Int";
        break;
    case TypeCode.String:
        s = "String";
        break;
    default:
        s = "string";
        break;
}
```

What am I doing wrong in either of those two approaches?

Comment: You don't have `case`s for `int?`, `double?` and `DateTime?`. The two `string` properties work fine for me.

Comment: Hello Klaus, yes that was the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your class you have properties like

```cs
public int? Id { get; set; }
```

But in your switch you are checking this case

```cs
case Type _ when propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(int):
```

and the problem is that `typeof(int?) != typeof(int)`

You need to add cases for your nullable types.

Comment: Ugh.... and double ugh... yes it was the fact that the properties were nullable. Thank you for the prompt response - and excellent eyes. :)