# Getting all properties, their data types, values and names from specified non-static class (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, class, properties

We have a test class:

```
class Animal
{
    public string AnimalName { get; set; }
    public string AnimalType { get; set; }
    public int AnimalAgeInMonths { get; set; }
}
```

and an instance to the class:

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
animal.AnimalName = null; // No name yet
animal.AnimalType = "Sheep";
animal.AnimalAgeInMonths = 7;
```

So I need a method that returns `System.Collections.Generic.List<(string[], string[], string[])>`. First string array represents names of all properties (i.e. `AnimalName`, `AnimalType`, etc), second array - values (i.e. *null*, `Sheep`, etc), and third array - data type, for example:

- `System.Int32` for `int`
- `System.Single` for `float`
- `System.String` for `string`
- etc

(these can be generated with the `typeof` keyword).

So overall, I need a method like this:

```
public List<(string[], string[], string[])> GetClassPropertyInfo(object Class)
```

which can be called like this:

```
GetClassPropertyInfo(animal);
```

Best regards,
-winscripter.

Comment: Can you show some of your attempts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using PropertyInfo to find out the property type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723934/using-propertyinfo-to-find-out-the-property-type)

Comment: Also, why do you need a *list* of the 3 string arrays? From what you are describing, it seems like you just need 3 string arrays, period. Please write out each element of this list completely for the `Animal` object you showed, so that exactly what you want is clear.

Comment: Yeah I understand why you want arrays, but why do you want a *list* of those arrays? From your attempt, it seems like you only add one element to this list, so why not just return a `(string[], string[], string[])`, instead of `List<(string[], string[], string[])>`?

Comment: @Sweeper well I don't (currently) know a way to return multiple string arrays at once, rather than adding them to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will get the name, type and value of each property (as strings) - you may use this as a starting point.   You can then store the name, type and value in any structure you need and return it.  Hope that helps.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;

class Animal
{
    public string AnimalName { get; set; }
    public string AnimalType { get; set; }
    public int AnimalAgeInMonths { get; set; }
    public int[] array { get; set; } 
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        Animal animal = new Animal();
        animal.AnimalName = null; // No name yet
        animal.AnimalType = "Sheep";
        animal.AnimalAgeInMonths = 7;
        animal.array = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
        
        class_info( animal );
            
    }
    
    static void class_info(object Class)
    {
        String val;
        
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in Class.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            // Property Name ...
            Console.WriteLine( propertyInfo.Name );

            // Property type (as string) ...
            Console.WriteLine( propertyInfo.PropertyType.ToString() );

            // Property value (as string) ...
            if ( propertyInfo.GetValue(Class, null) is null ) 
            {
                val = "null";
                Console.WriteLine( val );
            }
            else
            {
                // Property is an array, show values (as strings) ...
                if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsArray)
                {

                    IEnumerable array = propertyInfo.GetValue( Class, null ) as IEnumerable;

                    if ( array is null )
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine( "Array is null" );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Array values");
                        Console.WriteLine("------------");

                        foreach (var element in array)
                            Console.WriteLine(element.ToString());
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                   val = propertyInfo.GetValue(Class, null).ToString();
                   Console.WriteLine( val );
                }
            }

        }  
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The code works, that's great, but just like my attempt, it returns `System.(array type)[]` as string. If an array contains values like these: { "Foo", "Bar"}, then we can return `{ "Foo", "Bar"}` as string, which is not difficult. Can you edit the code to add support for arrays, by any chance?

Comment: @winscripter - code modified to include array property.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you only want 3 arrays. Each of those can be easily obtained with the Reflection API.

```
static (string[], string?[], string[]) GetClassPropertyInfo(object o) {
    // pass binding flags here if you want a different set of properties than default behaviour
    var properties = o.GetType().GetProperties();
    return (
        properties.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray(),
        properties.Select(x => x.GetValue(o)?.ToString()).ToArray(),
        properties.Select(x => x.PropertyType.Name).ToArray()
    );
}
```

Regarding the second array - you need a way to convert any property value (including `null`) into a `string`. Here I have just called `ToString`, and if the value is `null`, the result is also null. This is why the second array has nullable elements, and is of type `string?[]`.

Regarding the third array, `Name` returns the simple name, without the namespace. If you need that, you might want to do `x.PropertyType.FullName ?? x.PropertyType.Name` instead, or just `x.PropertyType.ToString()`.

Also note that you can totally just return 3 things in a [tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples), like I have done here, without putting them in a list.

That said, I would recommend creating a [record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) type for this:

```
record ObjectInfo(string[] Name, string?[] Values, string[] Types);
```

And you'd instead write:

```
return new ObjectInfo(
    ...
);
```

and also consider that maybe they shouldn't all be strings. I'd think that this makes more sense:

```
record ObjectInfo(string[] Name, object?[] Values, Type[] Types);
```